# Python: Issue printing to file special characters (Spanish alphabet)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making an an algorithm to classify words with the number of times they appear in a text given by a file.

There is my method:

```
    def printToFile(self, fileName):
    file_to_print = open(fileName, 'w')
    file_to_print.write(str(self))
    file_to_print.close()
```

and there is the str:

```
def __str__(self):
    cadena = ""
    self.processedWords = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(self.processedWords.items()))
    for key in self.processedWords:
        cadena += str(key) + ": " + str(self.processedWords[key]) + "\n"
    return cadena.decode('string_escape')
```

When I print the data through console there is no issues, nevertheless, when I do through file appears random characters.

[This is should be the output to the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nnoe.png)

[This is the output given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0FiU.png)

Comment: If I do that happens this: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc3' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)" Error generated at "file_to_print.write(str(self))"

Comment: The important question - what version are you on?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 right now

Comment: I've tried and the output is the same as before

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a encoding issue, try opening the file like this:
open("file name","w",encoding="utf8")
Utf8 is the most popular encoding but it might not be the real encoding, you might have to check out other encodings such as utf16

Comment: Won't work, unfortunately, the OP neglected to mention they are on Python 2,

Comment: I tried, but it throws me this exception: "TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: @Alkesst because this only works for Python 3. A similar `open` function is available in the `codecs` modules, so `import codecs` and uses [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open)

Comment: I used now file_to_print = codecs.open(fileName, 'w', "utf8") and still not working. Some idea?

Comment: I would try to move the dict logic out of the __str__ function,

Comment: that way you can then iterate over the dict and append to the file like this: file_to_print.write(self), it may work better